# What do you do when you discover a mistake in survey implementation partway through implementation?

Tags: survey, error, methodology, bias-correction, non-response

I'm working on a survey that is already partway through the implementation phase. It is a web survey, and unfortunately, one of my colleagues noticed that there was an error in the skip logic, leading to some questions not being answered by early respondents. It is impractical to restart the survey at this point, as many respondents have already taken the survey, but we do not have any way of identifying them (only some of the surveys were administered incorrectly). The bug has now been fixed, so we now have an inconsistent implementation problem affecting a particular subgroup of the survey respondents (and obviously this was non-random).

Obviously there is no "optimal" solution to this problem, but can anyone point to any helpful guidelines or ways of estimating the amount of error introduced by this problem?

Thanks!